# Unsubscriptions not cascading back to base observable in RxJava

Tags: java, groovy, reactive-programming, observable, rx-java

I have an observable ("o" in the example) in which I need to cleanup some state after an observer unsubscribes. According to [the docs](http://reactivex.io/documentation/observable.html), unsubscribing from other observers built on top of "o" should cascade back to "o".

That behaviour seems to work only on some examples. In the following code, I would expect the "cleanup" message to be printed three times, but on the last case (o1.throttleLast(...)) it isn't.

```
    def o = rx.Observable.create({ subscriber ->
        subscriber.add(Subscriptions.create({ println "cleanup" }))
    })

    o.subscribe({})
        .unsubscribe() // prints

    o.take(1)
        .subscribe({})
        .unsubscribe();  // prints

    o.throttleLast(1, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
        .subscribe({})
        .unsubscribe() // doesn't print
```

Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: It's a bug in `throttleLast`. I created an issue in https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/issues/1958 and also sent a pull request to fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bug of `throttleLast` has been fixed in RxJava 1.0.3.

Comment: Wow, that was great work! Sorry for the delay. Thank you for opening the ticket and working on the solution, it hadn't occurred to me it could be a bug in RxJava.